# Command pattern queue ordered by time?

Tags: c++, queue, command-pattern

I'm changing some code to use the command pattern and will store command objects in a queue.  The commands will need to be executed at specific times and so I will iterate over the list once per second to find commands to execute.

There will be a time associated with each command object and I will check this time against the current time (within a small threshold).  So I'll need to remove the command object from the list if its time matches and then execute it.  Generally there will be under 10 commands at any given time.  What collection data structure should I use and how do I remove command objects while iterating the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). This is a container that lets you pull the highest priority item. In your case, "higher priority" is "happens first".

C++ models a priority queue as the [`priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/) container adapter. This means that there's some other container inside of it that does the actual storage. This container is usually either `vector` or `deque`. (Random-access iterators are required.) It defaults to `vector`. So you can just declare:

```
std::priority_queue<T, vector<T>, Compare> queue;
```

where `T` is your element and `Compare` is a function that compares two `T` elements and returns `true` if the first is lower priority than the second. If you have `operator <` defined for your type `T`, it gets even simpler:

```
std::priority_queue<T> queue;
```

- To put an item in the queue: `queue.push(item);`
- To get the highest-priority element: `queue.top()`
- To remove the top item of the queue: `queue.pop();`

Note that `pop()` does not return the removed element; it just removes and destructs it.

Comment: So I guess this would involve using time as the priority?  Since I need to run the commands a specific times of day (e.g. 11:27:19 AM), do I keeping popping off commands until I pop one that is past the current time and then put that command back on the queue?

Comment: No, the priority queue keeps things ordered for you as long as your `Compare` function works. So when you grab `top()`, you know it's the highest-priority item. Just make sure that `Compare(a, b)` or `a < b` return `true` if `b` comes before `a`. So you'll just look at `top()`, execute it or not, and only `pop()` it if you executed it. No re-insertion needed.

Comment: Note that the usual definition of `<` for time won't work since it defines sooner as "less than" later. So you'll probably just want to define your own `<` for your class `T`.

Comment: Ahh I see.  How do you feel this compares with iterating through a vector (since the list will be small)?

Comment: @user since list is very small, you can probably use any data structure you wish. This is for your convenience! If you're goint to for example list pending commands in their execution order, then with plain vector you have to sort them out. And with `priority_queue` or `map/multimap` solution I posted below, you're ready to go. And you can keep eye on single item - one on the top of the structure to decide if any command has to be executed. No need to iterate.

Comment: I'd recommend `vector` because it will be faster than `deque` for small lists, and the code will be simpler.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: When you say use `vector` do you mean `vector` as the underlying collection of a `priority_queue` or just a plain `vector`?

Comment: `vector` as the underlying collection of `priority_queue`. Just like I have written in the answer.

Comment: For those scratching their heads like me, this requires ```#include <queue>```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Mike's solution is to use ordered map, which in case of STL is simply a `map`. You can keep time as a key and command as value. Depending on your case it may be more convenient than queue.

If two commands are allowed for the execution at the same time then you shall use `multimap`.

```
multimap<time_t, Command> schedule;

schedule.insert(pair<time_t, Command>(123456, formatHDDCommand));
```

Comment: Problem with a map based solution is that I need to allow for a little slippage so if the current time is 1 or 2 seconds past the target time and the command still hasn't executed I still need it to execute.

Comment: @User of course! You are not supposed to search the map for the exact time. Instead you have two other paths to utilize multimap. First, you can pick `begin` or `end` (depending on time representation) iterator and compare its time with current time. If current time is larger, you execute the command. Repeat this step as necessary. Second, you can use `find()` function with current time as an argument and iterate starting from iterator returned by `find()`. `find()` will "cut-off" commands, which time doesn't come yet.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought you were suggesting an exact key match, but you're using a map because of it's ordered property

Comment: Don't use `end()`; by definition it does not point to a valid element. Use `rbegin()` instead. Also, by the definition of the problem, you won't need to use `find()`. You will be . Overall, this is a much more complex solution than `priority_queue`, and you really don't need the O(logN) search time feature of `map`. You're not doing arbitrary searches; all your work will be with the earliest event, since you want to process them in order.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I also like your `priority_queue` more. But I speculate that in some circumstances, map/multimap can be more convenient. Maybe execution times will be binded to some other data structure or predicted? Then fast lookups for exact key => value pairs make sense and are justified. Also time granulation may be large enough to justify multimap. For example, in human scale, if time is represented by hours, then asking for commands to be executed at specified hour makes sense and multimap seems to be natural choice. This is human scale, but the same can be true in smaller scales.

Comment: `priority_queue` makes more sense for your hours example, too. The time scale isn't relevant. What you're doing with the structure is what's relevant. So long as you have a collection of elements with priorities, and you want fast access to the top priority item, then you want a priority queue. If you want arbitrary access, then you want a map, sure, but that is a whole different problem, and is not what was asked for here.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone my whole point was that the time scale isn't relevant. What is relevant is the nature of the problem, so if commands only need to be grouped in (few) time intervals, then `priorioty_queue` doesn't necessarily make more sense to me. But it was only one example. I'm not saying that `map/multimap` is better; I only speculate that in some cases it can fit. What we see in the question is rather excerpt of the larger problem, not the problem itself. BTW access to the top element of `map\multimap` is as fast as in the `priority_queue` - O(1).